# Defining sem_t in android ndk

Tags: android, java-native-interface, semaphore, android-ndk

I am porting some code from my libs in C++.

Note that android include library has the semaphore.h.

I include the files but when compiling it gives me an error: 'sem_t' does not name a type.

For example in linux would define my semaphore like:

```
    sem_t id;
```

Then would call:

```
    sem_init(&id, 0, initialCount);
```

In my Application.mk I am using:

```
    APP_STL := gnustl_static
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does the semaphore.h (or types.h, etc) have a typedef for sem_t? If not, you can't use it.

Comment: Yes it exists semaphore.h and it has sem_t defined like this.
typedef struct {
    volatile unsigned int  count;
} sem_t;

Comment: What version of ndk You are using ?

Answer (score 0):

Try to compile with `-lz -lm -llog -lc -L$(call host-path, $(LOCAL_PATH))/$(TARGET_ARCH_ABI)`

or just add the following line to Your `android.mk` :

```
LOCAL_LDLIBS += -lz -lm -llog -lc -L$(call host-path, $(LOCAL_PATH))/$(TARGET_ARCH_ABI)
```

It works for me